# Using a custom date formatter on a Telerik MVC AJAX bound property column

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2

I am using the latest version of `Telerik MVC` controls on my `ASP.NET MVC3` app with `razor`.

I have defined my grid structure as follows:

```
@(Html.Telerik()
     .Grid<GrantApplicationListViewModel>()
     .Name("grdGrantApplications")
     .Columns(column =>
     {
          column.Bound(x => x.FullName)
               .Title("Owner")
               .Width(200);

          column.Bound(x => x.CreatedDate)
               .Title("Created")
               .Width(90);
     })
     .DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding.Ajax().Select("AjaxGrantApplicationsBinding", "Home"))
     .Pageable(paging => paging.PageSize(30))
     .TableHtmlAttributes(new { @class = "telerik-grid" })
)
```

My view model looks like:

```
public class GrantApplicationListViewModel
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string FirstName { get; set; }
     public string LastName { get; set; }
     public string FullName
     {
          get { return FirstName + " " + LastName; }
     }

     public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
}
```

I have created a date formatter that I would like to use in my column to format the date:

```
public static class DateTimeExtensions
{
     public static string FormatDate(this DateTime instance)
     {
          return string.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", instance);
     }
}
```

How would I use this format method in my column to format CreatedDate?  I tried the following:

```
column.Bound(x => x.CreatedDate.FormatDate())
     .Title("Created")
     .Width(90);
```

..and I get the following error:

```
Bound columns require a field or property access expression.
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you have to bind to a property, so what you are doing will not work. What you CAN do is:

```
public class GrantApplicationListViewModel
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string FirstName { get; set; }
     public string LastName { get; set; }
     public string FullName
     {
          get { return FirstName + " " + LastName; }
     }

     public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
     public DateTime FormattedDate{ get{ return FormatDate(CreatedDate)}; set; }
}
```

And then

```
column.Bound(x => x.FormattedDate)
 .Title("Created")
 .Width(90);
```

(The code is not syntax correct so you have to clean it up :))

you could also do

```
column.Bound(x => x.FormattedDate)
     .Title("Created")
     .Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt}")
     .Width(90);
```

If I am not mistaken

Comment: I can do that, but shouldn't this be left to the view to format it?

Comment: Yes, but that would mean much more complex code, you would have to overwrite the "Bound" functionality .... so the easiest way atm is adding a property.

I found somewhere that you can also do a  .Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt}") maybe try that one first (not sure if that works though)

Comment: Is it possible to use my Format method because I want to use it site wide, if the date format has to change then I only want to change it once.

Comment: The you should set a global property that returns your formatting string. Like 
public string DateFormatString
{
 get
 {
   return "{0:MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt}";
 }

} And then .Format(DateFormatString())

Comment: @BrendanVogt You can't leave it to the view, because the Kendo Grid is running in JavaScript, not C#. Imagine you click a button on the page that loads new data into the grid - how can the JavaScript run a C# function on it? Kendo does support things like a "client template", which is defined in JavaScript and can do things like formatting.

Answer (score 2):

you can format date in `GrantApplicationListViewModel` class

```
public DateTime CreatedDate 
{
 get
 {
   return string.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", this);
 }
}
```

This works for me. Or else you can use in the below way

```
public DateTime CreatedDate 
    {
     get
     {
       return string.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", DateOfJoining);
     }    
    }
```

Comment: I can do that, but shouldn't this be left to the view to format it?